# MySQL update with same table values

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table named "users" that has the columns "firstname" and "surname". There are a thousand or so rows in the table.

I have now added another column named "search" and I would like to populate it with the values of both the first name and the surname separated by a space. For example, if firstname = Bob and surname = smith, i would like to populate "search" with "Bob Smith".

Can anyone advise on an update statement that selects these values and inserts them in to the new column?

Best regards, Ben.

Comment: Hi ben, i would suggest doing that with a simple php script. But I'm wondering if you want the search field so you can query on first and last name if so there is no need to combine them.

Comment: If you have two attributes: "firstname" and "surname" then surely you don't need another column with both in?  Isn't this just data redundancy?  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You don't NEED it, but you can then turn on full text indexing on that column and use it as keywords for searching.  Your query becomes easy because you can do WHERE keyword like '%Ryan%' instead of WHERE firstname = 'Ryan' or lastname = 'Ryan' and as you add more fields to your keyword search your query doesn't grow

Comment: @Michael, why run a PHP script for something that is native in the database?  Especially because we aren't even sure if PHP is one of Ben's languages

Comment: @taylonr - thanks.. I've learned something :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use...

```
UPDATE users SET search=TRIM(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', surname));
```

As an explanation, `CONCAT` simply concatenates (merges) the supplied fields/values, and `TRIM` will remove any leading or trailing spaces, hence ensuring that there are no issues if a firstname/lastname or indeed both are missing. See the MySQL [String Functions manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) for more information on these functions.

However, I'd be tempted to call the new column "name" (or indeed "full_name") rather than "search", as this is, at best, a somewhat misleading field name.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much, that was exactly what I was trying to do.

Regards, Ben.

Comment: @Ben No problem. Hope it goes well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
update users
set search = CONCAT(firstname, ' ', surname)
```

This script will update it.

I'm not sure about MySql, but Sql Server lets you set a field as a calculated column.  You can specify the calculation as "`ISNULL(FirstName, ' ') + ' ' + ISNULL(Surname, ' ')`" and set it as persisted so it doesn't calculate it each time. In that case, you wouldn't need an update script

Answer (score 0):

```
update `users` set `search` = CONCAT(`firstname`, ' ', `surname`);
```